# Sharing Video on facebook using facebook sdk4.0 from ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my iOS mobile app, i need to share/upload a video(either from photo library or captured using camera) on Facebook account. I am using iOS 8.0 & FacebookSDK 4.0. I have tried lots of code, but any of them not working. I have done the following steps successfully.
1) Login to facebook with a 'publish_action' permission
2) User does have a valid access token in `FBSDKAccessToken`
As mentioned in official FB document i have done this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
NSURL * selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:picker completion:nil];

FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = selectedVideoUrl;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video; 
//here now i have tried both the techniques mentioned below  
}
```

Now i have tried posting this content using `FBSDKShareDialog`, but its not working & throws error, also I have tried using `FBSDKShareAPI` like this

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.delegate=self;
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.shareContent=content;
[dialog show];
```

and like this

```
FBSDKShareAPI *shareRequest= [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
if ([shareRequest canShare]) {
    BOOL isSuccess=[shareRequest share];
    if (isSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"shared");
    }
}
```

How can i get this upload working?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @MingLi , when using FBSDKShareAPI it throws error for videoURL "....com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid value for videoURL:"

Comment: This usually means that the videoURL you passed in is not an asset URL. Can you show some more code wrt how you're getting the video url?

Comment: check my edited post, i have sent "selectedVideoUrl" received after picking  video from photo library. this is already an assetURL?

Comment: See Chris Pan's answer. Sorry for the confusion, I've also updated our docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` to get the asset library URL instead of `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.